# Ubuntu 18.04 White(strange)-Noise problem from headphone?( No Matter Sound is play or not)

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa, headphones, noise

I'm using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I enter Ubuntu after the Grub menu (It starts at log.) there is a constantly annoying noise from the headphone, but in Windows 10 there is no problem. The noise comes out only through my headphone, however the speakers work properly.

I have tried many of solutions below other titles but none of them resolved my issue. This weird noise never goes away. I even muted each input and output volume or listen to any video there is always boring noise. My laptop is an Asus n552vw and my kernel version is 4.15.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Solutions that I have tried :

- Running

  ```
  alsamixer - disable the loopback
  ```
- Adding `0` in the `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` file.
- `INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false` in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave`
- Adding options `snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` in the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- Change the option values `SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0`
  `SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=0` in the `/etc/default/tlp`
- Muted input volume and at `hdajackretask` changed pin 0x12 internal mic to not connected.

(I guess I collected almost all solutions under the single title at least)

Comment: For what it's worth [some people](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066565/static-noise-when-playing-sound) seem to have success with `pulseaudio -k`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue since I installed Ubuntu/Gnome last night. It seems Windows is playing silence while everything is paused, while Ubuntu is switching off the sound card.

The solution is:

```
sudo echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

source:
https://forum.level1techs.com/t/resolved-white-noise-when-not-playing-audio/149630

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.