# PulseAudio - Static noise through my headphones when any audio is played

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've tried almost everything I found on the internet including the solutions found here: [Static noise when playing sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066565/static-noise-when-playing-sound) but couldnt get it fixed. I even tried reinstalling pulseaudio.

Whenever an audio is played on Pop OS 18.04 (a wrapper around Ubuntu mostly), a very irritating static background noise is present. As soon as the audio stops, the static lingers around for a few seconds before vanishing. I've tried booting into a live USB Ubuntu 16.04 and checked the audio there to make sure it wasn't a hardware issue but the sound there was perfect.

Comment: Pop OS related questions are not supported on ask ubuntu. If you like to ask question here, verify if ubuntu 18.04 have the same background noise and update your question.