# Sound cracking/distortion in Ubuntu 20.04 installed on VB in windows 7

Tags: sound, 20.04

This is my first question here. I am a completely new to Linux and Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Virtual Box in windows 7. When I play videos from YouTube in Mozilla Firefox after about 50 seconds the sound gets cracking/distorted and after about 10-15 seconds the cracking/distortion goes away. It happens two to three times when I play a song of say 4 minutes.

Any advise on how to fix it would be immensely helpful. Please as I am new to Linux a step by step procedure would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue and (apparently) managed to solve it thanks to [this other question in this same forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033405/crackling-and-delayed-sound-after-upgrading-to-18-04).

Basically:

1. I closed the web browser (and any other application that emits sound)
2. I opened the Terminal and typed `killall pulseaudio`.

Been listening to a 3 hour ambient music video on Youtube and so far I heard no cracking.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without having to close your browser.  Open system monitor and kill the pulseaudio process.  The distortion happens every couple of days for me.  I dont know why, but this is a much easier fix and you dont have to close your browser and sign in again.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue. I personally did some trials with my virtual machine and found out that decreasing the RAM and CPU cores in the virtualbox settings solved the issue permanently.

Hope this helps!